# Looking for a Test Class for code coverage

Tags: unit-test, standardcontroller

I have created an Apex Class and VF page for Popup Alert. I am looking for a test class for the same.

Below is my Apex Class:

```
public class PopUpAlert
{
public Contact cont;

  public PopUpAlert(ApexPages.StandardController contact)
  {

   Contact cont = (Contact)contact.getRecord();
    cont=[select id,Customer__c from Contact where Id=: cont.ID];

  }

  public void setAlertVal(){
     cont.Customer__c = true;
     update cont;
  }
}
```

This is my Test Class:

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)

public class TestPopUpAlert 
{
    static testMethod void createContact()

 {

        Contact cont = new Contact();
        cont.FirstName = 'Bob';
        cont.LastName  = 'Test';
        cont.MailingStreet = '298 S. Ringo Street';
        cont.MailingCity = 'Little Rock';
        cont.MailingState = 'AR';
        cont.MailingPostalCode = '72201'; 


        insert cont;
        System.debug('created primary contact'); 

          Apexpages.StandardController sc = new Apexpages.StandardController(cont);
          PopUpAlert pua = new PopUpAlert(sc);
          setAlertVal sav = new setAlertVal(sc);
          test.startTest();

          cont.Customer__c = True;
          update cont;
          test.stopTest();

 }
}
```

I have been able to achieve 50% code coverage thus far but am looking for atleast 100% coverage.

Request your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Dear downvoter, It would be helpful if you can post comments about why you downvoted, This basically brings back to https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/is-salesforce-stackexchange-also-too-hostile-for-new-user

Comment: can you edit you question and let us know what problem are you facing, error message/exception you are getting. What lines are not covered?

Comment: @tanzysfdc, it would really help you to search through SFSE and other resources to read about test methodology. You're making a lot of very common mistakes that you can easily fix if you follow best practices. (1) you need to design your tests to cover all functionality, like the answer below says; (2) you need to make assertions to prove behavior; and (3) you need to create your own data, not use `seeAllData=true`.

Comment: One reason you're probably receiving downvotes is that you don't seem to have looked at the wealth of resources that are already available to you to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

In order to maximize your test coverage, you need to design test cases that covers every functionality of your class.

Note that the class PopUpAlert has two methods:

- The class constructor
- setAlertVal

Your test is covering only the class constructor part, thus you have 50% of code coverage.

I also suggest that you use the AAA pattern while designing your test code. You can read more about it here: http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrangeActAssert.